# use microphone to receive an inaudible tone?

Tags: android

I am doing a project. I want to use the speaker of computer to generate an inaudible tone and microphone on smartphone to receive this tone.

1.what software that can generate the inaudible tone (18- 20 Khz) through the speaker in PC ?

2.A code android to receive and analyse some features (frequency, amplitude,…) of this tone?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate sinus wave yourself as raw data sound. Compute sinus for your frequency in integer numbers and repeat them.

You can use AudioTrack with correct settings, and write method, propably several times or in loop.

Max amplitude can be get from MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude(). But for frequencies, you would have to use Fast Fourier Transform on raw audio. See for example [How to get frequency from fft result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

Most microphones i saw do not support so high frequencies. Are you sure your microphone will be able to capture such high frequency?

Comment: thanks a lots!!!
i checked and my mic (samsung s2) can receiver the sound <19khz