# fftw slight peak inaccuracy/drifting

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, fftw, portaudio

I am using fftw to get spectrum of an Audio Signal. I get Audio Samples in float32 and have also tried other formats using **PortAudio**. Then I take fft of it using fftw.  In all the formats, I have slight drift of frequency peak from actual frequency. My setup is.

- Signal Generator to supply sinusoidal signal.
- Sampling rate of 44.1KHz.

I am getting correct/relatively accurate readings till 10KHz. However as I gradually increase the frequency of Generator, I start getting offset. For example above 10KHz, this is what happens.

```
Actual frequency         Peak on Spectrum
10KHz                    10.5KHz
12KHz                    12.9KHz
14KHz                    15.5KHz
16KHz                    18.2KHz
```

The fft Code is as like this.

```
//Take Samples and do Windowing

 for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
     {          
         samples[i] = in[i];
         fft->fftIn[i] = (0.54-(0.46*cos(scale_fact*i))) * samples[i];
     }

//Zero Padding

  for(i=framesPerBuffer; i<fftSize; i++)
  {
    fft->fftIn[i] = 0.0;
  }

//FFTW Code

{  fftSize = fftSize;
  this->fftSize = fftSize;
    cout << "Plan start " <<  endl;

  outArraySize = fftSize/2+1;
  cout << "fft Processor start \n";
  fftIn = ((double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * fftSize));
  fftOut = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * outArraySize );
  fftOutAbs = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * outArraySize );

   fftwPlan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(fftSize, fftIn, fftOut, FFTW_ESTIMATE);


  //  fftwPlan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(fftSize, fftIn, fftOut, FFTW_MEASURE);
}

//Absolute response

  int n=fftSize/2+1;
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
  {
    fftOutAbs[i] = sqrt(fftOut[i][0]*fftOut[i][0] + fftOut[i][1]*fftOut[i][1]);

  }

  for(unsigned int i=0; i < n; i++)
  {   
     mainCureYData[i] = 20.0 * log10(one_over_n * fft->fftOutAbs[i]);
  }
```

I need some hints as to where/why this problem could be ?

The Hardware setup look fine as the peak shows correct on sndpeek application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually show the code where you calculate the frequency of the peak, but my guess is that the problem is here:

```
int n=fftSize/2+1;
```

This should most likely be:

```
int n=fftSize/2;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-do-i-obtain-the-frequencies-of-each-value-in-a-fft/4371627#4371627) and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/7675171#7675171) for an explanation of how to determine frequency from FFT output. (TL;DR: `f = Fs * i / n`)

Comment: For that, this code below generates the bins and then this array is plotted with FFT data to get a graph. The highest magnitude bin should be the frequency of signal. Which is what "drifts" away in my case.
`code
  for(int i=0; i < DEFAULT_FFT_SIZE/2+1; i++)
{
    mainCureXData[i] = ((double) i) / (DEFAULT_FFT_SIZE/2+1) * ap->getSampleRate()/2; `

`

Comment: Again it looks like an over-fondness for adding 1 to things. ;-) `DEFAULT_FFT_SIZE/2+1` should most likely be `DEFAULT_FFT_SIZE/2`. See the linked answers in my answer above to get a better explanation of how bin index maps to frequency. Note also that you probably don't want to look at the Nyquist bin.

Comment: the number of FFT points is `fftSize`, so I'd expect `f = Fs * i / fftSize`. The OP's variable `n=fftSize/2+1` is correctly used to process the lower half spectrum. It just shouldn't be used for the frequency computation part.

Comment: @SlethEye: indeed - I was just guessing as the relevant code was not shown. It looks like a different "off by one" error - see comment above.

Comment: Ok . Have tried `mainCureXData[i] = (((double) i) * 44100.0) / 8192 ;`
where 44.1K is fs and 8192 is fftSize but the issue persists. Intuitively, can +1  cause such behaviour ?

Comment: @jav321 with `fftSize=8192`, the "+1" causes a ~0.02% error in the frequency estimate, not the 5-14% error your results show. There probably are other sources of error or distortions.