# Get frequencies from FFT result using low sampling rate

Tags: signal-processing, fft, dft

I am working in research where we are using smart-phone camera to monitor users heart-rate using color variation as signal.
What I did is getting the red color channel every 0.1 second (10Hz).
The problem is that I am trying to use an FFT to get different frequencies that exist in the extracted signal and I used [this Java code](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html) where the FFT function get as input two arrays (one for real part and one for img part of complex numbers).
I saw also from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result) that I can compute frequencies from the FFT function's results by using the formula:

```
freq = i * Fs / N
```

where `Fs` is the sampling rate and `N` is the number of points(input).
The problem is that my sampling rate `Fs`, is too low (10Hz) and if I use above formula I am getting very low frquencies. Is there any other way to get frequencies?

Comment: If you sample at 10 Hz then you can identify frequencies in the range 0 - 5 Hz, which should be more than sufficient for (human) heart rate.

Comment: Correct! i was cofusing units. I just realized that 1Bpm = 1/60 Hz. Thanks for your comment