# Android library to get pitch from WAV file

Tags: java, android, fft, frequency, pitch

I have a list of sampled data from the WAV file. I would like to pass in these values into a library and get the frequency of the music played in the WAV file. For now, I will have 1 frequency in the WAV file and I would like to find a library that is compatible with Android. I understand that I need to use FFT to get the frequency domain. Is there any good libraries for that? I found that [KissFFT][1] is quite popular but I am not very sure how compatible it is on Android. Is there an easier and good library that can perform the task I want?

EDIT:
I tried to use JTransforms to get the FFT of the WAV file but always failed at getting the correct frequency of the file. Currently, the WAV file contains sine curve of 440Hz, music note A4. However, I got the result as 441. Then I tried to get the frequency of G4, I got the result as 882Hz which is incorrect. The frequency of G4 is supposed to be 783Hz. Could it be due to not enough samples? If yes, how much samples should I take?

```
//DFT
DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(numOfFrames);
double max_fftval = -1;
int max_i = -1;
double[] fftData = new double[numOfFrames * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < numOfFrames; i++) {
    // copying audio data to the fft data buffer, imaginary part is 0
    fftData[2 * i] = buffer[i];
    fftData[2 * i + 1] = 0;
}
fft.complexForward(fftData);
for (int i = 0; i < fftData.length; i += 2) {
    // complex numbers -> vectors, so we compute the length of the vector, which is sqrt(realpart^2+imaginarypart^2)
        double vlen = Math.sqrt((fftData[i] * fftData[i]) + (fftData[i + 1] * fftData[i + 1]));
        //fd.append(Double.toString(vlen));
       // fd.append(",");
        if (max_fftval < vlen) {
            // if this length is bigger than our stored biggest length
            max_fftval = vlen;
            max_i = i;
        }
}
//double dominantFreq = ((double)max_i / fftData.length) * sampleRate;
double dominantFreq = (max_i/2.0) * sampleRate / numOfFrames;
fd.append(Double.toString(dominantFreq));
```

Can someone help me out?

EDIT2: I manage to fix the problem mentioned above by increasing the number of samples to 100000, however, sometimes I am getting the overtones as the frequency. Any idea how to fix it? Should I use Harmonic Product Frequency or Autocorrelation algorithms?

Comment: There are a lot of related questions on this subject on SO already with some very good answers - try reading some of them and then come back if you still have specific questions.

Comment: Hi Paul, I actually read some of them and got even more confused by their answers. I am actually trying to use FFT to get the frequency (using the same FFT and Complex class as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325241/android-audio-fft-to-display-fundamental-frequency?rq=1). I understand that the result from calling the fft function is a Complex[]. However, my code always crashed at "Complex[] fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);" which I have no idea why. I will need to put "FFT.fft" in order to call the function from the FFT class.

Comment: It's quite a complex subject, and an FFT based approach isn't necessarily the best solution, but assuming you're going with an FFT then you'll probably want to get the FFT working on its own first. Once you have that working and understand what the FFT does you can then start adding the other building blocks: window function, pitch extraction, etc.

Comment: Okay. I manage to get the FFT working (or at least I think it is) by using JTransform. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result, I think the peakFrequency = index * SampleRate / NumSample. However, I always cannot get the correct frequency. I hae updated the post with my code.

Comment: If you're trying to determine the pitch of a musical instrument then it's a lot more complicated than just identifying the largest peak in the spectrum. Is this for a guitar tuner or something like that ?

Comment: It is for a music transcription tool. The user plays a series of music notes and I am supposed to capture all the music notes.

Comment: OK - what instrument, and is it polyphonic ?

Comment: Piano/voice. It will be mono, not polyphonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my mistake. If I take more samples, the accuracy will increase. However, this method is still not complete as I still have some problems in obtaining accurate results for piano/voice sounds.